# Why does my Python bot not work? (PyAutoGUI)

Tags: python, pyautogui

I coded a bot in Python that should automatically play Friday Night Funkin' (press the arrows when they are meant to be pressed) but for some reason it doesn't do anything. I took screenshots of the arrows when they are meant to be pressed and I made it so if python sees that the arrow is meant to be pressed (it sees the images/screenshots) it presses the corresponding key. I tried turning greyscale off but it didn't work. Is there any way to fix this or make it in a different way? I'm really new to Python and this is my first code so sorry if it's a stupid problem and question.

My FNF Version: https://poki.pl/g/friday-night-funkin

My images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxQdl.jpg

My code:

```
from pyautogui import *
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
import numpy as np
import random
import win32api, win32con

time.sleep(5)

while keyboard.is_pressed('q') == False:

if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('leftarrow.png', region=(1010, 50, 650, 200), grayscale=False, confidence=0.7) != None:
    pyautogui.keyDown('left')
    time.sleep(0.1)
    pyautogui.keyUp('left')

if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('rightarrow.png', region=(1010, 50, 650, 200), grayscale=False, confidence=0.7) != None:
    pyautogui.keyDown('right')
    time.sleep(0.1)
    pyautogui.keyUp('right')
    
if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('uparrow.png', region=(1010, 50, 650, 200), grayscale=False, confidence=0.7) != None:
    pyautogui.keyDown('up')
    time.sleep(0.1)
    pyautogui.keyUp('up')

if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('downarrow.png', region=(1010, 50, 650, 200), grayscale=False, confidence=0.7) != None:
    pyautogui.keyDown('down')
    time.sleep(0.1)
    pyautogui.keyUp('down')
```

Comment: This is actually quite a good question !

Answer (score 0):

maybe it is copy-paste lag, but there is no indention before "if"

use "not None" instead of "!= None"

use

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

your script as it now can be run only as python file, through console command or import.

Comment: What do you mean the script can be run only as python file, through console command or import? My current code or the one it would be after I do what you told me? Also does that mean I can't use any IDE (for example IDLE) to run it?